# optimum answer to do you often

Tags: grammar

Can you please clarify for me  which is  the correct answer to the following question:

Do you often have visitors?
a. Yes, pretty much every day
b. Yes, quite often
c. Not very often.

Comment: What are you trying to get at?

Comment: We obviously don't know what the correct answer would be unless we know if you often have visitors, but it could be any of the three. What makes you think one of them is incorrect? What is the context of the question? And American and British English use *quite* differently, so the answer may vary there as well. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional help; our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The question is odd: all three answers are acceptable. If I had to pick one, I'd say b), because it directly answers the question. a) implies a level of visitors that means 'often' (which is not stated) ie. why should 'every day' be 'often'? Technically, c) is not an answer, nor is it a sentence.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with **A** as it states the degree of how frequent visits are.

Comment: To what degree the questioner receives visitors is not the question. The question is, "do you have visitors 'often'?". This depends on what you mean by 'often'. 'Pretty much every day' would not be often at all for something like a museum. Response b) is the only one that answered the question, even though all three answers would be fine from a non-technical standpoint.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The closest would be to choose the degree of the visits~ you could also say __quite often__ but __A__ is the best-described.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain to me how *pretty much every day* more appropriately defines frequency of visitors than *quite often* or *not very often*? I must be missing something.

Comment: It gives a more specific figure rather than __quite often__

Comment: It also answers the question "How often do visitors come here?"

Comment: The point is, a more specific figure is not actually being asked for. The questioner is merely asking whether the respondee thinks they have visitors often. There is nothing about the 'rate' of visitors being asked.

Comment: Then my answer should not be downvoted as it also states how often they have visitors, but with a specific figure~

Comment: I am clearly out of my depth here.

Comment: You're missing the point (for the record, I didn't downvote you!). Answering a question that wasn't asked is not part of forming the 'best answer' to a question.

Comment: I did not say it was you who downvoted me. take it as this:
Q: "Do you often have visitors"?
A: "Yes"

------
Q: "How often"
A: "pretty much everyday"

Comment: Note: your second question: 'how often' was not asked at all, which is why an answer to it is superfluous/incorrect when choosing the 'best' answer.

Comment: "How often" and "Do you often" are equal in nature. they are asking for __frequency__.

Comment: ""How often" and "Do you often" are equal in nature." Incorrect. 'How often' - 6 times a week. 'Do you often'. No/Yes. I don't think there's any more to say about this one.

Comment: They both ask for frequency. the former with a specific figure and the latter with non-specific figure.

Comment: The meaning of "Do you often have visitors?" is purely subjective unless the questioner also defines their interpretation of 'often', e.g.: "By often, I mean 2-4 times a week or more" — in which case, it would be better to ask simply "**How** often do you have visitors?", because at least that would be likely to generate a quantified answer. In sum, unless it is supplemented with a definition of 'often', the question posed is unanswerable. As you say, A is the only meaningful answer: it is the only one that bypasses the question's subjectivity and is not itself also largely/totally subjective.